# How to query all time series of a given metrics in prometheus?

Tags: go, prometheus, victoriametrics

How to query the raw time series values of a specified metrics in prometheus without step? For example, I want to query how many datapoints are actually available in 1 minute, but when I specify step as 15s, 4 results will be generated regardless of the number of datapoints

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/api"
    v1 "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/api/prometheus/v1"
    "log"
    "time"
)

var (
    prometheus string        = "http://10.22.5.54:8481/select/0/prometheus"
    timeout    time.Duration = time.Second * 30
)

func main() {

    client, err := api.NewClient(api.Config{Address: prometheus})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error connect to the prometheus: ", err)
    }

    v1api := v1.NewAPI(client)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
    defer cancel()

    result, warnings, err := v1api.QueryRange(ctx, "up{app=\"activity-api\"}", v1.Range{Start: time.Now().Add(-time.Minute * 1), End: time.Now(), Step: time.Second * 15})

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error querying Prometheus: %s\n", err)
    }
    if len(warnings) > 0 {
        log.Printf("Warnings: %s", warnings)
    }

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `v1api.Query` instead of `v1api.QueryRange`, and add the needed interval in square brackets at the end of [series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors). For example, the following query should return raw samples for time series matching `up{app="activity-api"}` for the last 15 seconds ending at the given `time`.

```golang
t := time.Now()
result, warnings, err := v1api.Query(ctx, `up{app="activity-api"}[15s]`, t)
```

See more details [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.12.1/api/prometheus/v1#example-API-Query).

Internally the `github.com/prometheus/client_golang` package just queries  [/api/v1/query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries) HTTP endpoint, so it may be easier to just issue HTTP request to this endpoint without the need to figure out how to use `github.com/prometheus/client_golang`. For example, the following command will return raw samples from VictoriaMetrics cluster:

```
curl http://10.22.5.54:8481/select/0/prometheus/api/v1/query -d 'up{app="activity-api"}[15s]'
```

VictoriaMetrics also provides [APIs for exporting raw samples](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-export-time-series).

See also https://valyala.medium.com/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639 .